# Why didn't they mine dragonglass earlier?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Season 5, episode 5 *Kill the Boy*, There is a dialogue between Stannis and Samwell, where Stannis told Sam that there is dragonglass in Dragonstone

Even if he is not explicit in the amount of dragonglass, why didn't Sam ask more about it? And even after that Stannis is gone, there is still Davos, who know Dragonstone quite well. Can't he remind everyone that there is dragonglass in Dragonstone?

Comment: That's a pretty good question actually, I had forgotten about that scene. I guess the writers chose to forget it as well as otherwise, how would Jon get the chance to meet Daenerys?

Comment: I can totally buy that Sam thought Stannis meant "Yeah, there are bits of pieces of it in Dragonstone" rather than "there's a whole mountain of it that's suitable for mining."  Which might be the case of most deposits of it, and all most people know about it.

Comment: Didn't they have the wildlings to deal with? And just after that Jon's death and after that retaking the North?

Comment: "We have it in Dragonstone" doesn't necessarily mean lying around. But yeah, big oversight on Sam's part.

Comment: I thought the way they [hand waved](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HandWave) this was hilarious. "Oh! This secret forbidden book says there's dragonglass under Dragonstone! Just like Stannis told me in season 5 but never mind that, I thought it was one of those practical jokes he's famous for or something. Such a joker, that Stannis. I must tell Jon this dramatic new information at once!"

Comment: @user568458 nah, Sam is to serious to hand wave things. It's not like during this "discovery" scene he totally handwave a big information about L+R=J

Comment: And even if it is a small quantity, it is the only known weakness with valyrian steel, so even few quantities is good to take

Comment: @Kepotx are you wanting to hear anything from the books or a purely show-verse answer?

Comment: @Edlothiad I ask only for show (that's why there is no ASOIAF tag) : the books are different, As (SPOILERS !) Stannis is much more explicit and talk about mining dragonglass, and dragonstone is captured sooner by Cersei

Comment: Ah so you were aware, I was just checking in case it was an oversight :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL:DR**: They were too busy fighting in the North to go straight away and they wanted proof before committing men to go down to Dragonstone.

---

Let's look into the full conversation:

> Stannis: You don't look like a soldier. But I'm told you killed a white walker.
>   
>  Sam: I did, Your Grace.
>   
>  Stannis: How?
>   
>  Sam: With a dagger made of dragonglass.
>   Dragonglass? What the maesters call obsidian.
>   
>  Stannis: I know what it is. We have it in Dragonstone. **Why would obsidian kill a walker?**
>   
>  Sam: **I don't know.** I've been going through all the old manuscripts hoping to find something, and all I've learned is that the children of the forest used to hunt with dragonglass.
>   
>  Stannis: The Lady Melisandre told me that death marches on the Wall.
>   
>  Sam: I've seen it, Your Grace.
>   
>  Stannis: Seen what?
>   
>  Sam: The army of the dead. And when they come. We have to know how to fight them.
>   
>  Stannis: **Keep reading, Samwell Tarly.**

From the dialogue it's obvious that they don't know why the Dragonglass was able to kill the White Walker only that it did. For all they know it could have been lucky that Sam managed to hit it in a weak spot. Sam is still looking into it to see if it actually was the Dragonglass that did it.

As @Theik mentions in the comments Stannis saying they have it at Dragonstone could just mean "I have this awesome Dragonglass throne!" as he never elaborates on the amount. Though why Sam never questioned Stannis more about the amount and whereabouts seems off.

Now they also don't know if they could trust Stannis at this point as he is seen to be hell bent on power. This quote from episode 2 seems to confirm why they didn't start straight away, though why they didn't send anyone down to actually check is beyond me. (Though the most likely explanation is that Jon was too busy being killed, killing those who rebelled and taking the North back)

> Jon: This message was sent to me by Samwell Tarly. He was my brother at the Night's Watch, a man I trust as much as anyone in this world. He's discovered **proof** that Dragonstone sits on a mountain of dragonglass.

Then when Sam "finds out" about the Dragonglass he explains why he never thought to be confident about it before.

> Sam: It's a map of Dragonstone. The Targaryens built their first stronghold there when they invaded Westeros.
>   
> Gilly: That's dragonglass?
>   
> Sam: A mountain of it. Beneath the ground. **Stannis told me, but I didn't think...** This is important. Jon needs to know.

As to the end of "I didn't think" well we don't know:

- ...Stannis was telling the truth.
- ...to tell Jon.
- ...to remember this information until now.
- ...they actually had that much there.
- ...Stannis was talking about a load of the stuff.

As @Odin1806 comments below:

> Another thing I was going to point out is Dragonstone itself. As I understand it Dragonstone is both the island and the castle. It is possible that Sam thought of only Dragonstone the castle, even if Stannis had scouted the area himself and meant Dragonstone the island with obsidian in the caves beyond.

Comment: I can't check the script for episode 1 yet to see Sam's "revelation" as the site seems to be down but will check when I can.

Comment: Good point, but wasn't Davos aware of the dragonglass mine ?

Comment: @Kepotx I'm not sure on that, I've been looking to see if he was or not.

Comment: I don't think it is explicietly said in the Tv show that he knew about the dragonglass, but we can speculate that as he was hand of Stannis during a long time, he knew pretty well all secrets of Dragonstone

Comment: @Kepotx Yeah but Davos isn't shown to be the smartest of people, could be that he didn't know what the black caves were.

Comment: "I know what it is, we have it in Dragonstone" could also mean "we have a fancy doodad made out of obsidian so I know what stuff you're talking about". I wouldn't really read that as "we have a mountain full of the stuff."

Comment: @Theik Or my fancy ass throne is made out of it, you should come check it out some time.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder This is pretty much the same as the draft I had started, but another thing I was going to point out is Dragonstone itself. As I understand it Dragonstone is both the island and the castle. It is possible that Sam thought of only Dragonstone the castle, even if Stannis had scouted the area himself and meant Dragonstone the island with obsidian in the caves beyond.

Comment: @Odin1806 I didn't know they were both called the same. Feel free to post your own answer :)

Comment: Already deleted my draft! Like I said, we basically had the same answer. I don't see a point in answering the same thing more than once.

Comment: @Odin1806 Fair enough added in your point.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear why Sam didn't question Stannis about the dragonglass - Stannis wasn't very easy to converse with. He wasn't saying "there's plenty of it, let's have a nice friendly chat and I'll tell you all about it", he was saying "I've seen it, don't you dare patronize me by telling me what it is". Sam was probably too busy minding his manners to recognize this as a topic in need of following up.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld I'm not sure that your interperatation of how Stannis said that is correct but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There simply wasn't the opportunity to mine it until now.

Stannis abandoned Dragonstone when he travelled with his army to the wall.  At best, he left a small contingent of troops here.  To try and send troops BACK to Dragonstone would have been folly as the Lanisters already knew Stanis was at the wall, and would have taken control of the Island again, or at the very least watching it, especially with it's proximity to King's Landing.

Stannis then led his ill-fated attempt to take Winterfell, using as many troops as he could muster.  Then Jon did the same thing, using all the troops he could muster.

During Season 7, it's the first time that the Armies of the North have a break and can spare men for preparations, as well as a potential ally in possession of Dragonstone.  (or at least someone who isn't completely psychotic.)